# \DeclareMathSizes changing font size of regular superscripted text

Tags: fonts, superscripts

The font I'm using in Math Mode is displays a little to small for me when dealing with exponents. So, I'm using `\DeclareMathSizes` to change the superscript math font size, like this:

```tex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITSMath-Regular.otf}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\DeclareMathSizes{12}{12}{11}{8}

\begin{document}
This is \textsuperscript{some} text\footnote{This is a footnote}.
$$ e^{\pi i} + 1 = 0 $$ 
\end{document}
```

This has the desired effect of making the superscript size in math mode bigger, but it also makes normal superscript text bigger, as you can see here:

[image]

I do not want this behaviour. Is there any way to only make the superscript size bigger in math mode? For reference, this is how it looks without the `\DeclareMathSizes` call:

[image]

Basically, I want the small superscript for regular text like in the second picture, but I want the bigger superscript in math mode like in the first picture. Is there any way to achieve this? If it helps in any way, I'm compiling using XeLaTeX.

Comment: if you only need this at normalsize, change `\def\@textsuperscript#1{%
  {\m@th\ensuremath{^{\mbox{\fontsize\sf@size\sf@size#1}}}}}` to  `\def\@textsuperscript#1{^{\mbox{\scriptsize#1}}}` 
`

Comment: This would only change it for a particular call of `\textsuperscript` right? What I posted above is just a MWE, I'd want it to be global, especially because footnote marks in the text also get bigger.

Comment: no. if you define `\@textsuperscript` that way it affects every `\textsuperscript`